# How do I prevent my templated constructor to take the class as parameter when passing an object to a function

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17

I have a class that has a  templated constructor that initializes an array, but when
I pass my initialized object to an function, the function uses the templated constructor to make a copy(thats what I think).

Is there a correct syntax/way to prevent this from happening?

My code that defines the class, function and the main [run code](https://onlinegdb.com/Hkn8BgYHU):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <array>

template<typename T, typename Args>
class myClass{

public:
    std::array<T, 10> data;

    template<typename ... Element>
    constexpr myClass(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};

    myClass(const myClass& obj){
        data = obj.data;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Args>
constexpr auto myFunction(myClass<T, Args> obj){
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename Args>
constexpr auto myFunction(myClass<T, Args>&& obj){
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    myClass<double, std::tuple<int, int, double>> expr_obj;

    auto temp = expr_obj;//ERROR

    auto result = myFunction(expr_obj); //ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

The error message looks as follows:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr myClass<T, Args>::myClass(Element&& ...) [with Element = {myClass<double, std::tuple<int, int, double> >&}; T = double; Args = std::tuple<int, int, double>]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',43)">main.cpp:43:38</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:19:58: error: cannot convert ‘myClass >’ to ‘double’ in initialization
     constexpr myClass(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};
                                                          ^
```

I added the error message from CLion since its provides more information:

```
In instantiation of ‘constexpr myClass<T, Args>::myClass(Element&& ...) [with Element = {myClass<double, std::tuple<int, int, double> >&}; T = double; Args = std::tuple<int, int, double>]’:

cannot convert ‘myClass<double, std::tuple<int, int, double> >’ to ‘double’ in initialization
  304 |     constexpr myClass(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};
```

Comment: added a copy constructor

Comment: What is the template parameter `Args` used for?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I should removed it since it isn't needed in this piece of code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It seems kind of like an XY problem when I see a constructor parameterized over a type template parameter pack (facilitating, variadically, a varied number of arguments of possibly different _types_) used to initialize the (possibly less than all) elements of a `std::array<>` data member, where the latter is naturally holding elements all of the _same type_. Out of curiosity, could you give a few words on the context/use case of this? Do you need to be able to provide (constexpr) arguments to the constructor template function that are of _different types_? ...

Comment: ... Or, conversely, would `constexpr myClass(const std::array<T, 4>& arr) : data(arr) {};` not suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is constrain the elements of `Element` to be of type `T`.  That would look like

```
template<typename T, typename Args>
class myClass{

public:
    std::array<T, 10> data;

    template<typename ... Element, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Element>, T> && ...), bool> = true>
    //                             ^  this says only enable this template if all Element are T                ^
    constexpr myClass(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};

    myClass(const myClass& obj){
        data = obj.data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Might be worth it to also constrain on the size of the pack if, for whatever reason, OP wants it to be okay to construct via N instances of `myClass`. We'd only want to prevent this ctor for standing in for a special member ctor

Comment: I chosed to have 10 elements inside array for simplicity, my original code uses a static pow based on other paramters.

Comment: @AndyG If I did that they would no longer be able to default construct the object without also providing one.  Not sure if that is what they want or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver why should I use std::forward and not simply depack the parameter pack to initialize the array?

Comment: @M.Mac Actually it doesn't matter here.  I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just mark your templated constructor as [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
template <typename T, typename Args>
class myClass {
public:
    std::array<T, 10> data;

    template <typename... Element>
    explicit constexpr myClass(Element&&... input) : data{input...} {};

    myClass(const myClass&) = default;
};
```

Comment: Do note that this **only** fixes the code the OP is using.  If they used `auto temp(expr_obj);` instead of `auto temp = expr_obj;` then it would still fail to compile.  Since that is a common use case, this really isn't a working solution